# "Error creating transport" when connecting to a JMS topic in C#

Tags: c#, jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

I am trying to connect to a JMS topic in C# using the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ library. When trying to connect I get the following error "Error creating transport".

Here is my code.

```
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("remoting://" + textBoxIPAddress.Text + ":" + textBoxPort.Text);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(uri);
    LogService.Warning("CONNECTING TO:  activemq:tcp://" + textBoxIPAddress.Text + ":" + textBoxPort.Text);

    // create a connection
    if (username != null && password != null)
        this.connection = await connectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync(username, password);
    else
        textBoxMessages.Text = "INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD";

    if (this.connection != null)
    {
        await this.connection.StartAsync();
        LogService.Warning("START CONNECTION!");

        // create a session
        this.session = await connection.CreateSessionAsync(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);

        // get the destination
        IDestination destination = await this.session.GetTopicAsync(topic);
        LogService.Warning("GET TOPIC AND SUBSCRIBE TO IT!");

        // create a MessageProducer from the session to the topic
        this.consumer = await this.session.CreateConsumerAsync(destination);
        this.consumer.Listener += Consumer_Listener;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogService.Warning("FAILED TO CONNECT TO THE TOPIC! " + e.Message);
}
```

When testing this on my local machine, running ActiveMQ on localhost I do not get this error. Any help or explanation on what I am doing wrong is appreciated. My goal connection is to subscribe to a topic running on WildFly.

Comment: Keep in mind that WildFly uses ActiveMQ **Artemis**, not ActiveMQ "Classic," and while Artemis still supports the OpenWire protocol it isn't enabled by default in WildFly so you'll have to update the configuration to enable it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was information I was not aware of. I am unable to change the WildFly configuration. So is it there any way I can change my connection process in order to support ActiveMQ Artemis .

Comment: By default WildFly only supports clients using the core protocol from ActiveMQ Artemis. There is no C# implementation for this protocol. If you can't change the WildFly configuration to support OpenWire then you'll have to switch to a Java-based client which uses the core protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection URI is incorrect as you are passing "remoting://" to the connection factory which it would not know what to do with.  Your logging statement indicates you wanted "activemq:tcp://" which would be more in line with what I'd expect from a client connection.

As Justin pointed out in his comment you also need to enable Openwire in Wildfly as it isn't supported out of the box.